# In python / Spyder 3.3.2 I have problens with c = Count() sentence, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, count

```
The sentence:
>>>c = Counter()
```

prompts me:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    c = Counter()

NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined

Please help.

I was tying Dictionary features

```
>>> # Tally occurrences of words in a list
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
...     cnt[word] += 1
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the class in order to use it.

```
from collections import Counter
```

Example:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
    cnt[word] += 1
print(cnt)
```

Comment: Thanks RivensiL, it worked like a charm. Didn't know the collections library, I'll take  look @it.

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if it solved your question :)